# Bitwise operations on non numbers

Tags: javascript, operators, bit-manipulation

Somehow, JavaScript makes sense of the [bitwise operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) `NaN ^ 1`, `Infinity ^ 1` and even `'a' ^ 1` (all evaluate to `1`).

What are the rules governing bitwise operators on non numbers? Why do all the examples above evaluate to `1`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [ES5 spec](http://es5.github.com/), when doing [bitwise operations](http://es5.github.com/#x11.10), all operands are converted to [`ToInt32`](http://es5.github.com/#x9.5) (which first calls [`ToNumber`](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3). If the value is `NaN` or `Infinity`, it's converted to `0`).

Thus: `NaN ^ 1` => `0 XOR 1` => `1`

Comment: Those spec..... +1 And I thought it's `function bitwise(obj){
     if (typeof o !== "Number") return 1; }`

Comment: @gdoron: Gotta love the spec :-P

Comment: If they'll give me your rep, I'll. `:)` Just worth mentioning that the result depends of the second operand. Example: `"A" ^ 2 === 2 // true`

Comment: For the sake of completeness, any *non-number literal string* is **`NaN`** then `"a" ^ 1 = 1`

Comment: @Alexander. Almost, any non number (all other types like objects and arrays) evaluated to NaN. `/fndsjkn/ ^ 1 == 1`

Answer (score 3):

[ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) defines in 11.10 that arguments of binary bitwise operators are converted with ToInt32. And 9.5 that explains ToInt32 says in its first two points:

> 1. Let number be the result of calling ToNumber on the input argument.
> 2. If number is NaN, +0, -0, +Inf, or -Inf, return +0.