# Js switch by 2 variables always execute first case

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have 2 variables : `var1` and `var2`.

I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9235320/3917754 I try to implement it in my case :

```
switch (var1 | var2) {
    case ('Contact' | true):
        $('#btnCopyCompanyAddress').removeClass('hidden');
        $('#btnCopyPersonalAddress').addClass('hidden');
        break;
    case ('Company' | true):
        $('#btnCopyCompanyAddress').addClass('hidden');
        $('#btnCopyPersonalAddress').removeClass('hidden');
        break;

    default:
        $('#btnCopyCompanyAddress, #btnCopyPersonalAddress').addClass('hidden');
    }
```

but always first case is executed even if `var1` = `Company` and `var2` = `true`.

Comment: What do you think `'string' | true` evaluates to? Note that the quoted answer uses numbers and bitwise OR.

Comment: `'any string string' | true` === `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will always match the first case since `'any string string' | true === 1` results always `1`.

Bitwise operators treated both value as string so parsing string result `NaN`or `0` and `true` result `1`. The result would be calculates as `NaN | 1`, which results `1`.(If the value is `NaN` or `Infinity`, it's converted to `0`)

Refer : [Bitwise operations on non numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037811/bitwise-operations-on-non-numbers)

So that would not work in this case, instead try concatenation.

```js
switch (var1 + var2) {
  case ('Contacttrue'):
    $('#btnCopyCompanyAddress').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#btnCopyPersonalAddress').addClass('hidden');
    break;
  case ('Companytrue'):
    $('#btnCopyCompanyAddress').addClass('hidden');
    $('#btnCopyPersonalAddress').removeClass('hidden');
    break;

  default:
    $('#btnCopyCompanyAddress, #btnCopyPersonalAddress').addClass('hidden');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "+" instead of "|" :

```
function Check(var1, var2) {
    switch (var1 + var2) {
    case ('Contact' + var2):
        alert('1');
        break;
    case ('Company' + var2):
        alert('2');
        break;
    default:
        alert('0');
 }
}
```

Comment: @PranavCBalan, yes, you are right... Didn't noticed that