# Most efficient way to always return truthy using the least characters on an expression?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given:

```
(1);
(0);
(-1);
("a string");
("");
(null);
(undefined);
```

What can be put in front of the parenthesis to always return a truthy value.

A function defined as

```
var a = () => true;
```

will work.  So placing the letter a in front of each item in the list will have each one always return true (a thruthy value) since this creates a function call to "a".  However this requires calling a function every time.

```
a(1);
a(0);
a(-1);
a("a string");
a("");
a(null);
a(undefined);
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this.  I tried !! which won't work on falsey values.  Also tried ~ tilde but that won't work on (-1) resulting in 0 and two tildes ~~ but that won't work on (0).  Any other symbols that could be used to always return a truthy value or is a function the only way to do this?

Looking for an answer that **uses 1 or 2 chars**, but doesn't involve calling a function.  Using node.js so ES6 answers would work if there is one.

Comment: What is the practical use case for this?

Comment: true || (1);
true || (0);
true || ("a string");
true || ("");
true || (undefined);
:)

Comment: @ Mike McCaughan  Has to do with control flow.

Comment: @esnm 1|| is 3 chars, doubt you can do better

Comment: @esnm nope hasnt to do with control flow, has to do with ugly code...

Comment: @Jonas w  How is a("a string"); ugly code?  It's just a function call.  Looking for a more efficient (not ugly) way to do this.  Sticking to function call unless something better comes up.

Comment: @esnm yeah but why???

Comment: @Jonas w  Efficiency, avoiding the function calls.  Too long to explain here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the other side of the expression gets converted to a number (which I think it always does), 1 | x should never be able to return 0. So you can use that :

```js
console.log(1|(1),
1|(0),
1|(-1),
1|("a string"),
1|(""),
1|(null),
1|(undefined),
1|(console.log(3)),
1|(Infinity))
```

Got the idea from : [Bitwise operations on non numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037811/bitwise-operations-on-non-numbers)

Comment: `true` is not logged for the expressions?

Comment: @guest271314 he wanted a truthy value, not true

Comment: Ah, did not notice that part of requirement.

Comment: I knew this... :( but i thought you need "true"

Comment: @RohithKP I thought that as well but asked in guest271314 answer comments to confirm :)

Comment: After running some tests, this doesn't look any more efficient than the function call I described in the original post.  I guess the bitwise operator results in a function call to perform the bit manipulation.

Comment: @esnm that's interesting. Bit operations should be pretty fast, but maybe the casting to integer is what takes long. Still, how did you measure? It's hard to compare because you don't have to consider the time to run right side expressions

Comment: @juvian Ran the same right side expression a billion times using a function call and the bitwise operator. Each took 2.0 seconds to complete. Pgm: "var a = () => true, i; for (i = 0; i < 1000000000; i +=1) {1|("a string");} i;" // returns 1,000,000,000. Then changed the 1|() to a(). Same execution time. Used Google Chrome console to run the test.

Comment: @esnm yeah seems to be the same function cost

Answer (score 1):

You can use comma operator, include `true` following first portion of expression

```js
console.log((1, true),
(0, true),
("a string", true),
("", true),
(undefined, true));
```

You can alternatively use [`Logical NOT`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT) `!`, [Sign-propagating right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#%3E%3E_(Sign-propagating_right_shift)) `>>`, and `1`

```js
console.log(!((1) >> 1),
!((0) >> 1),
!(("a string") >> 1),
!(("") >> 1),
!((undefined) >> 1));
```

which can also be composed to meet requirement of preceding operator or expression by using `!(0 >> (<expression>))`

```js
console.log(!(0 >> (1)),
!(0 >> (0)),
!(0 >> ("a string")),
!(0 >> ("")),
!(0 >> (undefined)));
```

Comment: or even shorter : , !!1

Comment: @juvian Would return `false` for `!!(0)`

Comment: ? just mean to replace true with !!1

Comment: @esnm but 1 !== true, or you just want it to be truthy

Comment: @juvian just truthy.